# How I can Start a foreground service on clicking a widget of an android app and I don't want to open any another activity just want to run a service

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, widget, foreground-service

I have an android app, i want to implement a widget in which if we click a service on the background should start without opening any activity.
and want to display a toast message on home screen of Android Mobile with "Activated" Message.

I tried many things like but its not working.

Comment: Please give some details with what you tried with code samples.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.